# Where is my WETH?

Tags: opensea, wrapped-tokens

So I transferred some ETH to my Ledger Nano S Wallet to buy some NFTs on opensea.
Yesterday, I wrapped ETH to WETH. But I am not sure, if it actually worked.

In myetherwallet (and Ledger Live), it is not displayed. But in MetaMask it is.

[image: MetaMask Wallet (FF Addon)][image: Myetherwallet]

This or that way, not all Tokens are displayed congruently.

How can I check, that the wrap actually worked?

This is my address: https://etherscan.io/address/0x8d6343104e18dd8c67e8ccbabde00e4acfd19075

And here it shows, that i got one Wrapped Ether, if I understand that correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Your transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3663b1718ad33490328659b71b5e4bd81e673adc0eaf26a79a6441a1e68a43be) succeeded.

To make sure of it , you can check your address balance on the [WETH contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2#readContract).

[image]

Maybe you simply didn't add the WETH token view to your myetherwallet (I don't use myetherwallet so I don't know if it's a default token or not) . Did you try [this](https://kb.myetherwallet.com/en/tokens/how-to-add-custom-token/) ?

Anyway, the blockchain says you have 1 WETH.